# Что означает двойная буква в обозначении ячейки в google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Изучаю формулу в одной таблице и увидел такое:

```
=if(mid(tc($AI7,$AH7,Settings!$C$4,"sub"),4,5) = "aN:aN","",mid(tc($AI7,$AH7,Settings!$C$4,"sub"),4,5))
```

В текущей формуле интересуют следующие значения: AI7 и AH7

Знаю, что означает доллар. Знаю, что диапазон задаётся двоеточием. Но что значат две буквы подряд - не понимаю (диапазон от A7 до H7 исключается, т.к. там разные данные).

Информации не нашёл

Comment: В аглицком алфавите не так много букв, как порой нужно колонок на листе. Вот как количество колонок переваливает за 26, так и появляются колонки с двумя буквами. Относись к ним как к 26-ричным цифрам. Или можно перейти на R1C1-адресацию, там такой ерунды нету.

Comment: название столбцов идут от `A` до `Z`, а дальше `AA - ZZ`. Следовательно `AI7` - это ячейка пересечения 7й строки и столбца `AI`. Аналогично и `AH7`

Comment: а гуглотаблицы разве не подсвечивают ячейки, который используются в формуле?

Comment: @Akina точно, спасибо. Я что-то не подумал об этом.

Comment: @ZxNuClear спасибо. Я что-то не подумал об этом.

Comment: @Эникейщик просто они так далеко, что их не видно в подсветке (а вообще они были даже схлопнуты/скрыты, поэтому я их всё равно не увидел бы). Но вообще я не знал, что это всё-таки ячейка, а не хитрый способ указания диапазона. Теперь всё стало понятно))